# using a key to rearrange string

Tags: python, algorithm, string, encryption

Using Python I want to *randomly* rearrange sections of a string based on a given key. I also want to restore the original string with the same key:

```
def rearrange(key, data):
    pass

def restore(key, rearranged_data):
    pass
```

Efficiency is not important. Any ideas?

Edit:

- can assume key is hashable, but may be multiple types
- [definition of section for ignacio](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=define:section)

Comment: "Sections"? "Key"? You're going to have to do better than this...

Comment: I hope you're not using this for some form of cryptography/obfuscation - because it's very weak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can reinvent the wheel, but why not try an [encryption library](http://www.pycrypto.org/) first, if possible.

Comment: That would be ideal because I am already using pycrypto. I didn't find such an algorithm there, but the docs are quite limited - does one exist?

Comment: the algorithm in the library are all "tested" and widely used. your own algorithm will not be there. Pick the AES one and you will be fine

Answer (score 4):

Use `random.shuffle` with the key as a seed:

```
import random

def rearrange(key, data):
    random.seed(key)
    d = list(data)
    random.shuffle(d)
    return ''.join(d)

def restore(key, rearranged_data):
    l = len(rearranged_data)
    random.seed(key)
    d = range(l)
    random.shuffle(d)
    s = [None] * l
    for i in range(l):
        s[d[i]] = rearranged_data[i]
    return ''.join(s)


x = rearrange(42, 'Hello, world!')
print x
print restore(42, x)
```

Output:

```
oelwrd!, llHo
Hello, world!
```

Comment: Mine was faster, but yours actually works -- so I deleted mine.

Answer (score 1):

An implementation that reverses the shuffling with `sort()`:

```
import random

def reorder_list(ls, key):
   random.seed(key)
   random.shuffle(ls)

def reorder(s, key):
   data = list(s)
   reorder_list(data, key)
   return ''.join(data)

def restore(s, key):
   indexes = range(len(s))
   reorder_list(indexes, key)
   restored = sorted(zip(indexes, list(s)))
   return ''.join(c for _, c in restored)
```