# Rearrange data using python

Tags: python

SO following the question I asked before, ([Replacing special patterns in a string, reading from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25042042/replacing-special-patterns-in-a-string-reading-from-a-file?noredirect=1#comment38981072_25042042)) I seemed to resolve the problem there. But now I'm pretty much stuck with this problem for a month.

So with the code there , it reads the data from a file, parse it (so it divides the fields with tabs) but now I want the program to recognize the data ( so it needs to recognize in this example the authors, year of publication , isbn) and has to rearrange that data into a specific form/ pattern like for example:

```
INPUT DATA: Aubrecht, Christoph; Özceylan, Aubrecht Dilek; Klerx, Joachim; Freire, Sérgio (2013) “Future-oriented activities as a concept for improved disaster risk management. Disaster Advances”, 6(12), 1-10. (IF = 2.272) E-ISSN 2278-4543. REVISTA INDEXADA NO WEB OF SCIENCE 

AUTHORS:Aubrecht, Christoph; Özceylan, Aubrecht Dilek; Klerx, Joachim; Freire, Sérgio
YEAR: 2013
ISBN: 2278-4543


TEMPLATE 1: AUTHOR YEAR ISSN (Aubrecht, Christoph || 2013 || 2278-4543 )
TEMPLATE 2: YEAR ISSN AUTHOR (2013 || 2278-4543 || Aubrecht, Christoph )
TEMPLATE 3: ISSN YEAR AUTHOR (2278-4543 || 2013 || Aubrecht, Christoph )
```

The goal for this is to then import/export this data into Excel and then to a SQL database. I did my research and what I conclude (not sure if right) is that Django seems to be a good way to go since it can create templates (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/) or even with data frames using pandas dataframe  ([How to rearrange some elements as a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572326/how-to-rearrange-some-elements-as-a-data-frame), [Rearrange data for pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839329/rearrange-data-for-pandas-dataframe)) , but I'm not sure how to implement both, or if its even the best way to do it ( or if it's even possible for a program to recognize those elements and rearrange them).

Similar questions I've searched were: 
[using a key to rearrange string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345628/using-a-key-to-rearrange-string)  (didn't help)
[Rearranging letters from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948685/rearranging-letters-from-a-list)

Comment: _" it reads the data from a file, parse it (so it divides the fields with tabs)"_ In fact, you merely [tokenized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization) your input. Now you probably _have to_ [parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Parser) it

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I need to parse it, but i can't see a way to do it though